# Comma usage; introductory clauses

Tags: punctuation, commas, clauses

> In order to,  successfully fulfil the aim of the Partial Dispute Act, Section 1019bb DCPR stipulates that there is no direct remedy against a decision in subproceedings.

Should the comma after *In order to* be omitted? If it should, why is that?

Comment: Yes.  Because the comma splits parts of a verb form that belong together ("to fulfill") and because it erroneously signals to your reader that the introductory construct is "in order to" when it's really "in order to fulfill."  By the way, you may almost always drop the "in order" when you find "in order to"; by the by the way, I am not  the downvoter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all comma (,) is used where you need to separate things like:

> She has blue, red, green and black dresses.

or used where you need some halt in sentence not like period (.) but a shorter one like:

> Ginger Software announced today that Ginger Page, its new English
>   writing enhancement app, is now available for download on several
>   platforms.

In second sentence comma (,) suggests that the sentence isn't over yet; it's continuous.

In your case the sub-sentence in the sentence is continuous like this:

> In order to successfully fulfil the aim of the Partial Dispute Act (comma is rightly placed here).

After this part you can put a comma.

There is no need to divide this sentence as you have done.

Comment: I've done a little tidying, but I have no idea what the last sentence means, I'm afraid.